# C++ lambda, undefined behavior

Tags: c++, lambda

can someone tell me, why the following program fails?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <bool is_enabled = true>
class Aggregator {
public:
    Aggregator(std::function<char*()> data) : data(data) { }

    void fun() {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            std::cout << *((int *)data() + i) << std::endl;

        funInternal();
    }

private:
    template<bool enabled = is_enabled>
    void funInternal(typename std::enable_if<enabled>::type* = 0) {
        std::cout << "Feature is enabled!" << std::endl;
    }

    template<bool enabled = is_enabled>
    void funInternal(typename std::enable_if<!enabled>::type* = 0) {
        std::cout << "Feature is disabled!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::function<char*()> data;
};

template <typename T> 
class Multivalue : public Aggregator<true> {
public:
    Multivalue() : Aggregator<true>([&]() { return (char *) v.data(); }) { }

    void add(T a) { v.push_back(a); }
private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};

std::vector<Multivalue<int>> m; 
int main() {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        m.push_back(Multivalue<int>());

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < 1000; j++) 
            m[i].add(j);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        m[i].fun();

    return 0;
}
```

I know that the code is not really beautiful, but I want to understand the problem there. Somehow, the lambda expression seems to make trouble.

Thanks,
Moo

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem with copying the code

Comment: The lambda depends on the object it captures (`this`). Hence, you need custom copy/move operations to fix this dependency. I.e., a closure object that captures `this` has pointer semantics.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The lambda-expression uses `this->v.data` implicitly. Hence, it needs to store `this` as a data member of its closure type. The closure object is a data member of `this`, namely `this->data` (of the base class). If you copy `*this` to another object A, the closure object will be copied, and the stored `this` pointer will be copied. It will not be adjusted automatically to the destination A.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean. But I don't understand how I can fix that.

Comment: You'll have to recreate the lambda, or use a custom function object type that can adjust its captured variables on copy/move. Btw, here's a [live demonstration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a39bde37b53f8cf5) of the issue.

Comment: So, I need to track whenever the vector location changes and recreate the lamda then? That is not very convenient :/

Comment: You need to write copy/move operations for `Multivalue`, or disable them, or use a completely different approach. I don't quite see why the `std::function` data member is necessary, for example. CRTP could be used in this example as well, or good ol' polymorphism with virtual functions.

Comment: Both don't work because the aggregator class can have multiple subaggregators (not shown here) which also need access to the multivalue vector.

Comment: @dyp it is worse than that -- the above code captures `this` by reference, no?  Or is that blocked by the standard somehow?

Comment: @Yakk you can't capture `this` by reference; it makes as much sense as capturing 5 by reference, or doing `&this`.

Comment: @Yakk The Standard redirects accesses to id-expressions referring to both entities captured by copy and `this`, independent of what the capture-default is. They're redirected to the corresponding data members of the closure type.

Comment: Hmm.  For auto-reseating we need the passed up functions to take an `Aggregator*` as well as the sig and not capture `this`.  We could instead pass up a `std::function<Sig>(*)(Aggregator*)` -- a function pointer to a rebinder, to force the statelessness.  We would then store both, and only rebind as needed.  Could even do magic to do the static cast for derived?  ... prolly easier to just make derived do rebind.